# How to use parameter numbers and \foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, loops, foreach

Is there a way to use the TikZ `\foreach` command to do operations with parameters?

E.g. I would like to be able to write (just a silly example):

```
\newcommand{\foo}[9]{

    \foreach \x in{1,2,...,9}{
        \draw(0,#\x)--++(1,1);

    }
}
```

where `#\x` would mean the *x* th parameter of the command I'm defining with `\newcommand`.

This should come in handy since I'm writing macros that depend on global values that can be set arbitrarily. E.g. `\def\N{9}` would go in preamble and I'd write `newcommand{\bar}[\N]{...}`, but since I don't know beforehand how much parameters there will be, I can't define anything unless I write `\foreach \x in{1,2,...,\N}` and the above draw command.

---

What I actually like to do:

I'd like to have a command that plots some coordinates which are given. 
So I'd like `\foo{#1}{#2}{#3}` to expand to something like;

```
\draw plot coordinates {(360/\N*1:#1) (360/\N*2:#2) (360/\N*3:#3) ... (360/\N*\N:#N};
```

but I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: can be done in the same way as I already pointed out: `\def\saveCoordinates{}` and then instead of the `\draw` do `\xdef\saveCoordinates{\saveCoordinates(360/\N*2:#2)}`. However, I do not understand the meaning of `\N` here

Comment: Great thanks! Where did you point that out exaclty? Was it in this question, I don't seem to find it. `\N` would mean the fraction of the full circle and is also the number of command parameters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not reall understand what exactly do you want to draw, but maybe this helps:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\def\foo#1{\foo@i#1,,\@nil}%
\def\foo@i#1,#2,#3\@nil{%
  \draw(0,#1)--++(1,1);
  \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\foo@i#2,#3\@nil\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foo{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foo{1,2,3,4,5,6}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not what I asked for but way better! This helps a lot thanks!

Answer (score 1):

(*Substantially revised answer.*) The following should read in and draw as many arguments as you like, one at a time, provided that `\N` is defined and stores a positive integer.

```
\makeatletter
  \newcount\c@foo
  \newcommand\foo{%
    \c@foo=1\relax
    \@foo}
  \newcommand\@foo[1]{%
    \draw(0,#1)--++(1,1);%
    \advance\c@foo by 1\relax%
    \ifnum\c@foo>\N%
       \let\@tempa\relax
    \else
       \let\@tempa\@foo
    \fi
    \@tempa}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I know this is what I could do. But the example I gave is a simplification of what I really would want like to do. I've edited the question to make this clear.

Comment: I've revised my answer. It looks like Herbert's is more versatile, but this should also do what you want.